# credible interval equivalent of confint() for bayesglm() in Gelman et al's 'arm' package?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, credible-interval

How do I extract a credible interval ala confint on a glm object when working with the object returned by bayesglm() in arm?

Comment: You could write a method for `confint` for class `bayesglm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I do not have enough rep to comment I will put my comment as an answer. See this article, https://it.unt.edu/sites/default/files/bayesglm_jds_jan2011.pdf. Page 7 and up will be useful for you.

Comment: thanks, the use of sim() + quantile() is what i was getting at with my answer. guess this is the way to do it for now.

Comment: Well it appears you can't just use sim and quantile as bayesglm isn't actually finding a posterior. For this reason I try to avoid bayesglm. You could do the fit in JAGS. JAGS output gives the credible intervals.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the terminology in the pdf. What does "’simulates’ which are used in place of an actual empirical distribution" mean?

what does sim() on a bayesglm() object do, if not sample from the posterior?

Answer (score 0):

credible intervals can be inferred using sim() with quantile(). But I would still be interested if there's a more direct way to do this.